# set theory - prove that $S \subseteq \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} $ is Countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

Hey I have to submit an assignment to the University, I would really appreciate your thoughts on the proof I wrote.

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} $ :

$f \in S \iff  \exists n \in \mathbb N ,\forall k>n \rightarrow f(k)=0$

prove that S is countable.

---

let there be $g:S \rightarrow \mathbb N×....×\mathbb N$

so that $~~g(f) =  ~<f(0),f(1),f(2)...,f(n)>$ so that $~\forall k>n f(k)=0$

Let $~~f,h \in S ~~ $assume that $~~g(f)=g(h)$ we will show that $~~f=h$

$g(f) = <f(0),..f(n)>$

$g(h) = <h(0),...h(m)>$

so $f(0)=h(0), ... ,f(m)=h(n)$

$m=n~$ by a set definition and $~\forall k>m,n ~ f(k)=0=h(k)$

so $\forall x \in \mathbb N ~ f(x)=h(x)~$ and therefore $f=h$

so $|S| \leq |\mathbb N×....×\mathbb N| = |\mathbb N |$
and therefore S is countable.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{N}$? That is, how many factors does it have?

Comment: You are using $\mathbb{N}^n$, not $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. They are very different. The former is a finite product of countable sets. The latter is a countable product of countable sets. You need:

$g:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{N} \times \cdots$

Once you prove that the countable product of countable sets is countable, then you can prove the original statement.

Comment: i have proved it, i just wanted verification for the other part

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Are you suggesting that $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is countable?

Comment: @Arthur No, I am commenting on what the OP is proving vs what the OP stated needed to be proved.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Then what does "Once you prove that the countable product of countable sets is countable" mean? Because to me, that looks like you're saying that $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is countable.

Comment: @Arthur I was providing a hint rather than giving the answer. Had the OP attempted to prove that $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ was countable, I was expecting the OP to run into a contradiction.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Fair enough. It was just a bit too obscure for me to catch on to it, apparently.

Comment: @Arthur I probably should have been more clear. While I understand what I was thinking, you are correct that someone else reading it may not have understood what I was going for based on how I worded it. So, good catch, and thank you for clarifying.

Comment: How can i prove that $g: \mathbb N×⋯× \mathbb N -> \mathbb N$ is Injective? what function should i use? @InterstellarProbe

Comment: @bliblo Arthur and I are saying that the original problem statement is false. $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ does NOT imply that $S$ is countable. Counter-example: $S = \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. Suppose there exists some bijection $g:\mathbb{N} \to S$. Then, we can apply something similar to Cantor's diagonal argument. We build a tuple $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ such that our tuple does not match $g(n)$ on the $n$-th number. This is an element that $g$ cannot map, a contradiction to $g$ being a bijection.

Comment: suppose $S \not= \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, can i prove that it's countable using $\mathbb N×⋯×\mathbb N$? if so how can i prove that $\mathbb N×⋯×\mathbb N$ ~ $\mathbb N$ @InterstellarProbe

Comment: Defining $g$ sets you on the right track. However $g:S\to\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} $and note that you can find an injection by using $g$ from $S$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ which is definitely countable.

Comment: Suppose $S = \{1,2\}^\mathbb{N} \subsetneq \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

Cantor's diagonal argument still works, and $S$ is not countable.

Comment: Unreadable. Too many symbols, no punctuation, inconsistent capitalization, can't tell where one sentence ends and the next begins.

Answer (score 1):

For all n in N, show
S(n) = { f in S : for all k > n, f(k) = 0 } is countable.
Conclude S = $\cup_n$S(n) is a countable union
of countable sets, hence countable.

This is the same proof used to show there are countably many
polynomials with interger, or with rational, coefficients.